# Can I cancel a flight because of COVID-19 and use the voucher for same time and flight cheaper ticket?

Tags: cancellations, covid-19

I have booked a ticket for future travel but now see the price has come down considerably. Should I cancel because of coronavirus and rebook with voucher?

Comment: It’s hard to work out what your actual question is. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to travel on a different date?

Comment: Much more information is needed. What airline? What flight dates? What country do you live in, and what country (or countries) are the arrival and destination locations? All of these factors may affect what you can do, or what the airline thinks you can do, or what various governments require the airline to do.

Comment: @MJeffryes She said she wants to rebook on exactly the same flight because the price has decreased.

Comment: Id be very careful around terms and conditions here to ensure you wouldnt be committing fraud by doing what you propose to do.

Comment: If you are allowed to board the flight, I do not see why the company would agree to cancel your flight. And of course, if you are not allowed to board the flight, the whole schema does not make sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the airline can answer this as it depends on their current cancellation policy and the type of ticket you purchased.

Answer (score 6):

You can't just 'cancel because of coronavirus'. If the airline is still listing the flight then you can only cancel on whatever terms you agreed to when you booked.

If your ticket is fully refundable then you can cancel and rebook, if you can actually get the refund. Many airlines are refusing to pay refunds at present.

More likely, there will be some penalty for cancelling, which could be part or all of the fare you've paid. Even with the price reduction, it's likely that you'll end up paying more overall.

If you're hoping to get a full refund (as cash or voucher) then you'll have to wait until the airline cancels the flight, in which case there will be no flight to rebook onto.

Comment: FYI, Many airlines are offering free cancellations even if your purchased a non refundable flight.

Comment: @AnishSheela: it all depends on the airline. Ryanair dumped their fee for rebooking until end of August (but you still need to pay extra if the fare is higher). Lufthansa allows for cancellations.

Answer (score 4):

There are some risks associated with it.

It can take a significant time to issue a voucher depending on airline. So, you may need to wait much time to get the voucher and pay for the flight again with it. (My Scoot ticket voucher is currently 2+ months waiting to be issued.)

The voucher also may have some conditions applied, such as it can only be valid after a specific date.

There is a (not so rare) chance that the airline company goes bankrupt and the voucher you have is of no value. Since you completed the transaction by getting issued a voucher, you cannot contact your credit card company and file a dispute.

Clarify everything before cancelling, else, depending on how much closer is your travel, you can end up paying more.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the type of your ticket you purchased. No airline will cancel your booking because of the corona. I tried that. I didn't have a non-refundable ticket (or whatever it is called). However, I had a flexible ticket so I just changed the dates of the flight.

Comment: That's a wrong assumption. I had experience otherwise.

Comment: Incorrect. I've literally had an email from AirNZ today - flight cancelled - reason: Covid19 pandemic. And a month beforehand they gave me the option to have a credit refund.