# How can I make American airlines honor their travel voucher?

Tags: american-airlines, vouchers

February 2020 I bought tickets to Barcelona from New York City which I cancelled due to the pandemic. Like everyone else I got a travel voucher which was supposed to be valid till December 2021. The original voucher was for roughly $600. I used $300 of it in a itinerary in July 2020. I got the balance back in another travel voucher. What American airlines didn't tell me in advance before I made the purchase was that the new voucher would only be valid for a year and not till Dec 2021. The validity of the $300 voucher lasted till July 2021 and apparently it was written in a small font at the end of the email that I received along with the $300 voucher. I wasn't even aware of this. Now when I try to use the voucher it says invalid. Is there any way I can get the money back that was mine in the first place ?

Comment: You might be too late, as you have probably clicked agreement to the terms.  You could and should have rejected the travel voucher, since you were entitled to get your money back.

Comment: I just don't understand why airlines get to put expiration date on the money they rightfully owe to you. Can I do the same with my mortgage, I wonder.

Comment: @alamar _My guess_ is the original voucher being good through Dec 2021 was based on some legal requirements due to covid bailouts. Once the original voucher was used in part, the remainder owed was then time limited per standard accounting practices.

Comment: @gerrit: OP would have been entitled to get their money back if *the airline* had cancelled the flight.  But OP says "I cancelled", in which case the airline was not obliged to refund, and could offer a voucher instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right, I misread.  OP made a mistake to cancel the flight; very likely, the flight would have been cancelled due to the pandemic anyway (OP didn't say what date their flight was for).

Comment: @alamar - For the same reason that they put an expiry date on shopping vouchers, because otherwise it has to be accounted for (on their books) as a *potential* loss every year forever. After a while, those potential losses can be very considerable.

Comment: @Valorum What's a shopping voucher?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - [A gift certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_card).

Comment: @Valorum Gift certificates, in many states of the US, cannot have expiration dates (and gift *cards* are required to not expire for a minimum of 5 years federally).

Comment: @Joe - A very quick look at [state law in the US regarding gift cards](https://www.ncsl.org/research/financial-services-and-commerce/gift-cards-and-certificates-statutes-and-legis.aspx) would suggest that these consumer-friendly laws still allow the issuer (in most cases) to declare a card abandoned after a certain period (presumably for liability purposes) and only a very few prevent the issuance of an expiry date.

Comment: @gerrit It doesn't matter you cancel, they cancel in 2020 they were not giving any money back just travel credit - heck the airline companies were struggling to stay afloat they couldn't afford to return any of the money back - only a promise of future flights. But in the end it all worked out and I got my money back (Answer below)

Comment: @juneHunter They have a legal obligation to give the money back, and governments were ensuring the companies wouldn't fail as a consequence.  Condor tried to give us a voucher for a transatlantic flight, but [we declined and got our money back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157093/2509).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wasn't even aware of this.

That is unfortunately your problem.

I think the best you can do here is to call them and ask nicely. American Airlines played by the rules that you (unknowingly) accepted so there is very little you can do to push them. If you can't any traction with the first agent, you can try again with another agent.

Comment: This can all be summed up as: 'murica

Comment: This worked. I used the chat application and they directed me to customer relations through the website. The key is to talk to different representative and maybe one of them is kind enough to understand your situation and remedy it. I asked nicely and the fact that AA extended coupons expiring till May 2021 helped as well.

Comment: @o0'.  sadly it's more likely a corporate-level response and isn't limited to just one country.